# How do I in JDBC read a possibly null double value from resultSet?

Tags: java, jdbc, null, double

I have a column in my database that is typed `double` and I want to read the value from it using a JDBC ResultSet, but it may be null. What is the best way of doing this? I can think of three options none of which seem very good.

Option 1: Bad because exception handling verbose and smelly

```
double d;
try {
   d = rs.getDouble(1);
   // do something
} catch(SQLException ex) {
   if(rs.wasNull()) {
      // do something else
   } else {
     throw ex;
   }
}
```

Option 2: Bad because two fetches

```
s = rs.getString(1); // or getObject()
if(s == null) {
  // do something else
} else {
  double d = rs.getDouble(1);
  // do something
}
```

Option 3: Bad because Java rather than SQL conversion

```
s = rs.getString(1); // or getObject()
if(s == null) {
  // do something else
} else {
  double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
  // do something
}
```

Any suggestions on which way is better, or is there another superior way? And please don't say "Use Hibernate", I'm restricted to JDBC code only here.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Option 1 is closest:

```
double d = rs.getDouble(1);
if (rs.wasNull()) {
  // do something
} else {
  // use d
}
```

It's not very nice, but that's JDBC. If the column was null, the double value is considered "bad", so you should check using `wasNull()` every time you read a primitive that is nullable in the database.

Comment: note that there's no sqlexception when retrieving null primitives from a result set.  the default value for that primitive is returned in such cases (0 for int, 0.0 for double, etc....).  Hence why .wasNull() is a necessary evil.

Comment: I had the exact same reaction as @JosefPfleger once I realized how vanilla JDBC works with regards to nulls. If you want to continue using plain SQL, though (as opposed to adopting an ORM) and avoid this debacle altogether, I suggest using Spring's `JdbcTemplate`, which takes care of all those pesky null checks for you.

Answer (score 19):

Depending on your JDBC driver and database, you may be able to use a boxed type and cast:

```
Double doubleValueOrNull = (Double)rs.getObject(1); // or .getObject("columnName")
```

It will be `null` if the column was `NULL`.

Be careful to check this still works if you change database.

Comment: This is not working for me when querying HSQLDB with oracle syntax for tests.

Comment: This worked fine for me for MySQL, and nicer on the eyes than .wasNull()

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
rs.getObject(1)==null?null:rs.getBigDecimal(1).doubleValue()
```

Answer (score 8):

Or with java 8 you can do this:

```
Double dVal = Optional.ofNullable(resultSet.getBigDecimal("col_name"))
                .map(BigDecimal::doubleValue).orElse(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version to retrieve a nullable field:

```
val parentId = resultSet.getObject("parent_id") as Double?
```