# How to check for null when using getDouble("columnName")?

Tags: java, json, android-studio, null, double

I need to retrieve a double value from a database, which could potentially be stored as null, so I need to detect whether or not it is null before or after retrieving it. However, the method getDouble("columnName") actually returns 0 if the value in the database is null.

I have tried the solutions provided here to no avail (Android Studio says it's unable to resolve wasNull() and getObject():

[How do I in JDBC read a possibly null double value from resultSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103460/how-do-i-in-jdbc-read-a-possibly-null-double-value-from-resultset)

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
beer.setRating(beerObj.getDouble("myRating"));
if(beerObj.wasNull()){ //'Cannot resolve method wasNull'
}
```

And this:

```
Double doubleVal = (Double)beerObj.getObject("myRating"); //'Cannot resolve method getObject()'
```

I have other properties that I am retrieving using getString("otherColumnName") and that is retrieved properly so I assumed that the beerObj was retrieved properly as well.

Is there another way to check if the double value is null in the database before retrieving it?

Comment: Both `wasNull()` and checking `getObject("columnName") == null` are valid solutions. Could you please share the errors you're getting?

Comment: Hi @Mureinik, when I do the following: beer.setRating(beerObj.getDouble("myRating")); 
            if(beerObj.wasNull()){      
            } I get "Cannot resolve method wasNull()". Also, when I try the getObject() method, I get "Cannot resolve method "getObject()"

Comment: but what error are you getting? Can you please edit your question with the code snippet and the exact error?

Comment: @Mureinik, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for me to post. I did add the lines that I'm having issues with in my original post. As I said in my comment, Android Studio is unable to resolve those methods, so I cannot compile it without first resolving those methods. In that case, there won't be compile errors.

Comment: Why are you using the JDBC tag and citing JDBC questions when your question is about JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes put it in your where clause: `"WHERE columnname is not null"`. If there is a record returned then it isn't `null` if there isn't a record returned then it is `null`.

Comment: Thanks @brso05, this solution worked. I ended up doing what you suggested, and then using the beerObj.has("myRating") to check if that property exists. I have to admit though, I am a little disappointed that I cannot check for a null value from the front end. Thanks again!

Comment: @Koercion no problem glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try `if (resultset.getObject("columnName") == null)`. It's hard to tell from your original post if you were trying to use `getObject()` without passing in a value.

Comment: Hi @MHardwick. I entered if(beerObj.getObject("myRating")==null) but I still get the 'Cannot resolve method getObject()' message.

Comment: Can you add some more context? Specifically, from the declaration of beerObj on?

Comment: I retrieve a response from the database as a JSON object. JSONObject beerObj = beersJSONArr.getJSONObject(i); (the i is because it is in a for loop). The rest of the properties are retrieved properly, and the code compiles and the data is retrieved properly when I comment out the getDouble line.

Comment: Ah, ok! You're using a JSONObject instead of a ResultSet. JSONObjects don't have wasNull or getObject methods. Try `if (beerObj.isNull("myRating"))` instead.